# Javascript and HTML5 Audio Player with song to select

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So to be clear I have all the audio files in the same folder as the html file, I had it playing with one song but I need the user to be able to choose a song from the list I believe my problem is something with the source within my audio tags, yes I know I am using a global variable. Yes I also am aware of the audio controls built in with html5, I wanted to make my own play and pause buttons, and they work but like I said I can't change it so the user can pick a song from the list.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #D1D1D1;
        }

        #title {
            text-align: center;
        }

        fieldset {
            display: block;
            border: 4px solid black;
            background-color: #22F4ED;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        #div1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        table {
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var selSong;
        function check(song) {
            selSong;
            var sng = document.getElementById(song);
            var dropDownSel = sng.options[sng.selectedIndex].value;
            if (dropDownSel == "selectsong") {
                alert("Please select a song");
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "AtAGeorgiaCamp-Meeting") {
                alert("You selected At a Georgia Camp Meeting");
                selSong = '"AtAGeorgiaCamp-Meeting.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "GoodByeBroadwayHelloFrance") {
                alert("You selected Good Bye Broadway, Hello France");
                selSong = '"GoodByeBroadwayHelloFrance.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "HowYaGonnaKeepThemDownOnTheFarmAfterTheyveSeenParee") {
                alert("You selected How Ya Gonna Keep Them Down On The Farm After They've Seen Paree");
                selSong = '"HowYaGonnaKeepThemDownOnTheFarmAfterTheyveSeenParee.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "K-K-K-Katy") {
                alert("You selected K-K-K-Katy");
                selSong = '"K-K-K-Katy.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "OhHowIHateToGetUpInTheMorning") {
                alert("You selected Oh How I Hate To Get Up In The Morning");
                selSong = '"OhHowIHateToGetUpInTheMorning.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "PackUpYourTroublesInYourOldKitBag") {
                alert("You selected Pack Up Your Troubles In Your Old Kit Bag");
                selSong = '"PackUpYourTroublesInYourOldKitBag.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "TwelfthStreetRag") {
                alert("You selected Twelfth Street Rag");
                selSong = '"TwelfthStreetRag.mp3"';
            }
            if (dropDownSel == "YesWeHaveNoBananas") {
                alert("You selected Yes We Have No Bananas");
                selSong = '"YesWeHaveNoBananas.mp3"';
                alert(selSong);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Music Player</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <table>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="playAudio('selectedSong');">Play</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="pauseAudio('selectedSong');">Pause</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="div1">
            Pick a song:
            <select id="song" onchange="check('song');">
                <option value="selectsong">Select a Song</option>
                <option value="AtAGeorgiaCamp-Meeting">
                    At a Georgia Camp
                    Meeting
                </option>
                <option value="GoodByeBroadwayHelloFrance">
                    Good Bye Broadway, Hello
                    France
                </option>
                <option value="HowYaGonnaKeepThemDownOnTheFarmAfterTheyveSeenParee">
                    How
                    Ya Gonna Keep Them Down On The Farm After They've Seen Paree
                </option>
                <option value="K-K-K-Katy">K-K-K-Katy</option>
                <option value="OhHowIHateToGetUpInTheMorning">
                    Oh How I Hate To Get Up
                    In The Morning
                </option>
                <option value="PackUpYourTroublesInYourOldKitBag">
                    Pack Up Your Troubles
                    In Your Old Kit Bag
                </option>
                <option value="TwelfthStreetRag">Twelfth Street Rag</option>
                <option value="YesWeHaveNoBananas">Yes We Have No Bananas</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <audio id="selectedSong">
        <source src=selSong type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <script>
        function playAudio(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).play();
        }
        function pauseAudio(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).pause();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is because only IE can play mp3 songs with html5, try to convert the format mp3 to ogg and do this, mp3 works on IE and ogg works on chrome, opera, safari, mozilla, etc, keep mp3 format too.

```
<source src=selSong type="audio/mp3">
<source src=selSong type="audio/ogg">
```

Also you'll need to add this (for example) but in all of your songs

```
selSong = '"TwelfthStreetRag.ogg"';
```

Comment: I conveniently have mp3 and ogg versions of each song! tried your recommendation and it still doesn't work: